# Why on running below program , output of sizeof(a) in void print_size(int a[ ]) function is 8 whereas in int main( ) function sizeof(a) is 12?

Tags: c, sizeof

This program is about finding size of integer array and its elements size ,printing the size of
array `a[]` in function `void print_size(int a[])` ,it is showing `sizeof(a)` as 8 whereas in `int main()`function `sizeof(a)` is 12. How  is the output
for `sizeof(a)` function given in `void print_size(int a[])`is 8 but in `int main()` function `sizeof(a)` is  12 ,on running the program .
Here is code given below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
void print_size(int a[])
{
    printf("%d %d ",sizeof(a),sizeof(a[3]));
}
int main()
{
   int a[]={1,2,3};
   printf("%d %d \n",sizeof(a),sizeof(a[-1]));
   print_size(a);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions.

Comment: Passing results of `sizeof` (its type is `size_t`) to `%d` (requires `int`) invokes *undefined behavior*. The correct format specifier is `%zu`.

Comment: and since you're on a 64 bit machine, that's a size of 8 bytes for the 64 bit address

Comment: If your thinking is that when you pass `a` to `print_size`, the size of the array is passed, you are expecting something that is literally impossible. Imagine if some other function that calls `print_size` only receives an `int *`. How could `print_size` possibly know what the "right" size is?